# FCC Accessibility Options For Disabled Question

Tags: discussion

Can this question regarding [FCC Accessibility Options For Disabled Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/166761/33287) be reworded such that it doesn't violate our "no specific legal advice" rule?

If not, is there a related useful question we could post to address at least some of the concerns in the developer community regarding the recent exemption expiration?

I reworded the initial title of the question to make it more of a question (as opposed to a statement of disbelief). Personally, I find the question body to still be a little to reactive, but didn't want to overstep with edits. Since the question is deemed off-topic anyway, maybe a more extensive edit would help.

In particular, the question addresses an editorialized news article about the topic & ask "is this article serious?" Would focusing on that aspect of the original question help?

Having reviewed some of the [IGDA video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLVEo4bPIUOskdGVEeft1afc8gIWCiLAa6&v=M2OVSHHPFrA) in which Karen Peltz Strauss of the FCC discusses what the CVAA means for games, my take is that the article is viewing things somewhat out of context.

Comment: FWIW I think the original question has been deleted... so it makes it difficult to discuss if you're not seeing any "traction" on the meta.